# Build opencv in windows

Tags: windows, opencv, error-handling, build

On my Windows, I've installed codeblocks (17.12 with mingw), extracted opencv(4.3) and called cmake.

Now I want to build the opencv.cbp.

I see many errors from codeblocks telling that it can't compile the code and that code needs to be edited. Is this usual?

[image: Image : one simple Error]

Comment: Can you share your code and error messages in text form?

Comment: it's not my code . it just a opencv lib . i need to build opencv before typing code and when i build it see errors .

Comment: Nico , see this topic . i have this eror too in codeblocks . don't know in scope : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41091562/cant-build-opencv-3-1-on-windows-using-mingw?rq=1